# Problems restarting neo4j 1.7 server

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to restart my Neo4j instance and see no errors in either my messages.log or console.log.

I do see recovery notices in messages, however my start script always returns:

```
waiting for server to be ready............................................... BAD
```

console.log:

```
9/12/12 6:37:48 PM org.neo4j.server.NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer INFO: Starting Neo Server on port [7474] with [20] threads available
9/12/12 6:37:48 PM org.neo4j.server.NeoServerWithEmbeddedWebServer INFO: Enabling HTTPS on port [7473]
9/12/12 6:37:48 PM org.neo4j.server.database.Database INFO: Using database at /db/data
```

messages.log:

```
2012-09-12 18:37:49.059+0000: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...
2012-09-12 18:37:49.067+0000: [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log.1] logVersion=244 with committed tx=18015029
2012-09-12 18:37:55.391+0000: [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log.1] entries found=203005 lastEntryPos=8387712
2012-09-12 18:37:55.391+0000: Internal recovery completed, scanned 203005 log entries. Recovered 23260 transactions. Last tx recovered: 18038289
2012-09-12 18:37:55.392+0000: XaResourceManager[/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log] sorting 0 xids
2012-09-12 18:37:55.393+0000: XaResourceManager[/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log] checkRecoveryComplete 0 xids
2012-09-12 18:37:58.033+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names rebuild id generator, highId=4 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.053+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys rebuild id generator, highId=7 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.069+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.propertystore.db.index rebuild id generator, highId=6 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.096+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.propertystore.db.strings rebuild id generator, highId=16265 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.108+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays rebuild id generator, highId=1 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.507+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.propertystore.db rebuild id generator, highId=3052890 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.903+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.relationshipstore.db rebuild id generator, highId=9188555 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.929+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore.nodestore.db rebuild id generator, highId=1183312 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.942+0000: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/neostore rebuild id generator, highId=6 defragged count=0
2012-09-12 18:37:58.946+0000: XaResourceManager[/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log] recovery completed.
2012-09-12 18:37:58.946+0000: Recovery on log [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/nioneo_logical.log.1] completed.
2012-09-12 18:37:58.962+0000: TM opening log: /srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/tm_tx_log.1
2012-09-12 18:37:58.994+0000: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/index/lucene.log.2]. Recovery started ...
2012-09-12 18:37:58.994+0000: [/srv/neo4j/graphdb/data/index/lucene.log.2] logVersion=99 with committed tx=10257784
```

Answer (score 0):

Recovery of lucene takes too long. Please use `bin/neo4j console` to start it once in foreground mode to finish the recovery.